# NSTimeInterval equivalent in android

Tags: java, android, ios

Does anyone know how to implement

```
 NSTimeInterval stamp=[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you would require `new java.util.Date().getTime()`

Not specific for Android in any way though. Just Java.

It returns a `long` primitive with the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static long getDateInterval(Date oldDate, Date newDate) {
    long dateIntevalInMilis = newDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime();
    return dateIntevalInMilis 
}
```

This function will return the interval of two dates in miliseconds